# "Enforce" overrides in C#

Tags: c#

I have a abstract base C# class with a couple of methods that has to be overrided. How can I enforce this? Right now I throw an exception as a base implementation

> ```
>     public virtual string Description
>     {
>         get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
>     }
>
>     public virtual string ErrorMessage
>     {
>         get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
>     }
> ```

That solution however feels a bit wrong and very little intuitive ... Are there other ways to solve this in C#?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make the properties (these are not methods in your example) [abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5(VS.71).aspx).

```
public abstract string Description{ get; }

public abstract string ErrorMessage{ get; }
```

Comment: Damn ... Didn't know that. Of course. I only thought abstract was applicable on classes.

Comment: If you just want a getter (like in the question) you can use `public abstract string Description { get; }`.

Comment: Don't you have to use the { get; } part? I don't think it compiles without it.

Answer (score 3):

In case of method you should make them abstract

```
public abstract void Method();
```